# PHP contact form white screen

Tags: php, html, css, forms, contacts

my php contact form works and sends me an email when people fill it out. what is happinging though is when they click submit, the screen goes white and nothing happens. I want the page to refresh or redirect to another page. How Can I get it to refresh?

here is my PHP:

```
<?php 

// define variables and set to empty values
$name_error = $email_error = "";
$name = $email = $message = $success = "";

//form is submitted with POST method
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
  if (empty($_POST["name"])) {
 $name_error = "Name is required";
  } else {
    $name = test_input($_POST["name"]);
    // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
    if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$name)) {
      $name_error = "Only letters and white space allowed"; 
    }
  }

  if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
    $email_error = "Email is required";
  } else {
    $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
    // check if e-mail address is well-formed
    if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
      $email_error = "Invalid email format"; 
    }
  }

  if (empty($_POST["message"])) {
    $message = "";
  } else {
    $message = test_input($_POST["message"]);
  }

  if ($name_error == '' and $email_error == '' ){
      $message_body = '';
     unset($_POST['submit']);
     foreach ($_POST as $key => $value){
        $message_body .=  "$key: $value\n";
   }

      $to = 'whitandr@oregonstate.edu';
      $subject = 'Contact Form Submit';
     if (mail($to, $subject, $message_body)){
      $success = "Message sent, thank you!";
      $name = $email = $message = '';
  }
 }
```

}

```
function test_input($data) {
  $data = trim($data);
  $data = stripslashes($data);
 $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
  return $data;
```

}

Comment: Provide the html form and the file name for each code part you are presenting. Shouldn't you have a `require 'functions.php';` (or similar) in your php code?

Comment: you can use <?= "<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0"> ";?> then it will reload, meta should be place in <head> tag but it will work same as header('Location: yourpage.php'); after the codewas executed the echo'd meta will be lost when it refresh!

Answer (score 0):

You can add this to the end of your script to redirect the user `header('Location: success.php');`